# How to check if some IE window is already opened by javascript within that window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

our **web app** doesn't support **IE** but customer wants to use **call center** functionality which is only supported in IE due to **activeX control** of call center. 
As a work around, when user clicks on call button in chrome, web app opens the callCenter.html page in IE by using **URL Alert protocol** , and that **callCenter.html** page starts the initialization of activeX control for further operations. So far its OK.
Problem is, if callCenter.html window is already opened in IE, and user clicks again on call button in chrome, it opens another window of callCenter.html in IE, which results in activeX control initialization again and here it gets malfunctioning, since that activeX control is already loaded and running in previous IE window.
So please suggest, if there is some way, by which we can detect if callCenter.html window is already opened in IE, and if its already opened, it should update the calling parameters for call center.
Many thanks for your kind suggestions

Comment: This is the first time I have seen this tangible "cross-browser" solution (pun not intended). Usually, people would show a page saying "X browser is required for Y feature", and not force the computer to open a new browser from a completely different browser. Correct me if im wrong, but this is introducing headache along the way, if not it is already intrusive.

Comment: opening IE browser isn't any issue. some other modules of 3rd party also run in IE and we are doing the same and client is OK with that. But for this call center requirement, activeX gives error if already running in some other IE window.

Comment: I suggest you to check the **window.closed**. The closed property returns a Boolean value indicating whether a window has been closed or not. Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_closed.asp